# How many different polynomials of degree n can we get from this?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, permutations

$p$, $q$, and $r$ are positive integers. How many different polynomials of degree $n$ are there if:

$$P(x) = (x − 1)^p * (x − 2)^q * (x − 3)^r$$

I get that $p + q + r = n$, but can't figure out how to solve it using permutations. Could anyone please explain it "for dummies"?

Comment: The next step is to show that $(p_1,q_1,r_1)$ gives the same polynomial as $(p_2,q_2,r_2)$ if and only if $p_1=p_2,q_1=q_2$ and $r_1=r_2$. This will characterise exactly what combinatorial problem you need to solve.

Comment: stars and bars  .

Comment: or, better, [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the number of ways to write $n = p+q+r$ with $p,q,r$ positive integers. This is called an (ordered) partition of the number $n$. For a first expression to compute it, we look at it the following way: Fix a $p$, then fix $q$, then $r = n-p-q$. Assume we have fixed a $1 \leq p \leq n-2$. Then for $q$ we have $1 \leq q \leq n-p-1$, thus $n-p-1$ possibility choices. The last one, $r$, is then fixed.

So in total, you will have
$$\sum_{p=1}^{n-2} n-p-1$$ possible triples, and I am sure you can find ways to compute this sum. :)

Comment: Technically, the term partition of an integer is reserved to cases where the order doesn't matter (i.e. the two partitions $(1,2,3)$ and $(3,1,2)$ of $6$ are considered the same).  Otherwise, this looks correct to me.

Comment: Ok, I edit it. :)

Comment: This comes to $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$, which I don't think is correct. Consider $n=3$. Your answer gives $1$, but I count $10$: $(p,q,r)\in\{(3,0,0),(2,1,0),(2,0,1),(1,2,0),(1,1,1),(1,0,2),(0,3,0),(0,2,1),(0,1,2),(0,0,3)\}$. I see you say "positive integers", where I think we need "non-negative integers", since $0$ is a valid exponent.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) approach.
$$
\overbrace{\star\star\star}^p\,\mid\overbrace{\,\star\,}^q\mid\,\overbrace{\star\star}^r
$$
The arrangements of the $p+q+r$ stars and $2$ bars gives an enumeration of the different polynomials. Since $p+q+r=n$, the number of polynomials is
$$
\binom{n+2}{2}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
$$